# Is there any way to debug .COM files with OllyDbg?

Tags: windows, debugging, ollydbg

Is there any way to debug a .COM executable with OllyDbg? It seems to only accept EXEs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

COM files are 16bit DOS programs, and don't run natively under windows (they run through an MS-DOS subsystem, see [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COM_file)), as such ollydbg can neither attach to it nor debug it (as its a 32bit *windows* debugger).